# Aufzählung: trennt "sowie" die Glieder einer Aufzählung?

Tags: usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, list

Aus den Beförderungsbestimmungen der BVG (Berliner Verkehrsbetriebe) stammt folgender Satz:

> "Vollständig zusammengeklappte Fahrräder sowie Kleinkindfahrräder bzw. fahrradähnliche Roller (mit einem maximalen Felgendurchmesser bis zu 12,5 Zoll) gelten als Handgepäck."

Meine Frage hierzu:

Bezieht sich "(mit einem maximalen Felgendurchmesser bis zu 12,5 Zoll)" auf "Vollständig zusammengeklappte Fahrräder", auf "Kleinkindfahrräder bzw. fahrradähnliche Roller" oder auf beides?

Kennt jemand vielleicht eine semantische Regel hierzu?

Comment: Ich kann dir leider keine Regel nennen. Ich denke die Klammer bezieht sich auf den Teil nach _sowie_ , da es sich um eine Felgengröße für Kinder (bis ca. 1m) handelt.

Comment: Beim ersten Durchlesen des Textes haette ich gesagt, dass sich die Klammer nur auf "fahrradaehnliche Roller" bezieht. Im Zweifelsfall einfach die Verkehrsbetriebe anrufen und nachfragen. Das hilft Dir natuerlich nicht weiter zu wissen ob die Beförderungsbestimmungen grammatikalisch korrekt sind. :(

Comment: Danke für die Antwort, interessant finde ich, dass mir die Interpretation, der Text in Klammern beziehe sich nur auf die "fahrradähnlichen Roller", nicht spontan in den Sinn gekommen ist. Auf jeden Fall beginne ich Verständnis dafür zu entwickeln, dass sich die Schlüssigkeit und Eindeutigkeit einer Aussage nicht immer mit gutem Stil unter einen Hut bringen lassen. Ich möchte jedenfalls keine Beförderungsbedingungen schreiben müssen!

Comment: Es würde Sinn machen, dass sich die 12,5 Zoll auf alle drei beziehen, jedoch erscheint mir das auch für zusammenklappbare Räder sehr wenig.

Comment: Das ist ein schlecht formulierter Satz; es gibt zu viele möglicher "Klammerungen".

Answer (score 2):

M.E. kann man in dem Beispiel keine hundertprozentig sichere semantische Regel anwenden. Die Bedeutung ergibt sich nach meiner Meinung aber aus dem Inhalt: Entweder Klappräder oder bestimmte nicht klappbare "Fahrzeuge", die wiederum nach Größe und Bauart näher spezifiziert sind. "Sowie" trennt also zwei Varianten; die Klammerzusatz stellt m.E. sicher, dass die "fahrradähnlichen Roller" sich im Größenbereich von Kinderrädern bewegen.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Antwort! Das sehe ich genauso, befinde mich aber nicht in Kongruenz mit der Meinung des BVG-Sachbearbeiters. Unabhängig vom Inhalt meiner Frage: Sprache ist immer spannend!